# Docker bind troubles

Tags: docker, bind

Probably beginner question - but why copy do not work?
I have played with volumes and mounts - what I need is simple shared directory that i can read / write from both host and container (host has to write file, container pick it up and write response in another file)

```
docker run --rm -it --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/sdt,target=/sdt alpine ls -al /sdt && cp /sdt/temp /sdt/temp2
total 8
drwxr-xr-x    4 root     root           128 May 30 20:39 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 May 30 21:09 ..
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            64 May 30 20:39 input
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             5 May 30 20:35 temp
cp: /sdt/temp: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your command isn't parsed as you think. What happens here is:

1. Your shell runs a docker command:

```
docker run --rm -it --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/sdt,target=/sdt alpine ls -al /sdt
```

2. Then runs a local `cp` command

```
cp /sdt/temp /sdt/temp2
```

And there is no `/sdt/temp` on the host.

Try to put the whole command in quotes so that everything is run in the container:

```
docker run --rm -it --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/sdt,target=/sdt alpine "ls -al /sdt && cp /sdt/temp /sdt/temp2"
```

Once this is done this behaves as expected.